# multiplying through a maximum function with random variables

Tags: expected-value, expectation-maximization

Does this hold?
$$
\max(0,\vec{a}) \cdot \max(0,\vec{b})
= \max(0,\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})
$$

Comment: Where you say "Beginning with the inside of the expectation", the following line is wrong. Say $gx<0$ and $gy<0$, then your LHS$=0$, but your RHS$>0$.

Comment: (-1) I am done with this question. This is at least the **third** time you have changed the question, after an answer was posted to the previous version. (And the second time since you *accepted* the answer!) You can post a new question, or at the very least add an update without deleting the old content (which leaves answers orphaned). If there is some [underlying question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/339776), you should just post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update:** I am putting my old comment here as the answer, since the question has now been changed to just that!

First note that since 1) the dot product produces a scalar result, and 2) the question involves no expectations or probabilities, then your question is really equivalent to:

"Does it hold that $\max[0,a]\max[0,b] = \max[0,ab]$ ?"

That is, the fact that $x,y,g$ are vectors or that $g$ is random are unimportant.

The answer to this simpler question is **no**. An easy counter-example is $a=b=-1$.

---

> The answer below was to the original question, which asked if it was true that
>   $$\mathbb{E}\big[(x^Tg)_+(g^Ty)_+\big] = (x^Ty)_+$$
>   where (I believe the intent was) $g\sim\mathrm{N_{0,I}}$

(Note: I am using "positive part" notation here, where $x_+\equiv\max[0,x]$. Similarly, I will use matrix notation for dot products: $x^Ty\equiv\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$.)

A simple counter-example to your formula is the following. For $x=y=1$, the right hand side is simply $1$, while the left hand side is
$$\mathbb{E}[(g_+)^2]=\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[g^2]+\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[0]=\tfrac{1}{2}\neq{1}$$

---

If you remove the $()_+$ part, the formula works, since $g\sim\mathrm{N_{0,I}}$ by definition implies $\mathbb{E}[gg^T]=I$, so we have
$$\mathbb{E}\big[(x^Tg)(g^Ty)\big]
= x^T\,\mathbb{E}\big[gg^T\big]\,y
= x^TIy = x^Ty
$$

---

For the scalar case, the formula with the $1/2$ correction-factor holds
$$\mathbb{E}[(gx)_+(gy)_+]=\tfrac{1}{2}(xy)_+$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. But this does **not** hold in the general vector case (i.e. if $x$ and $y$ are not parallel).

Comment: How did you carry out this calculation?  In your example the left hand side is $\mathbb{E}((g1)(g1))=\mathbb{E}(g^2)=1$.

Comment: I changed "positive part" notation from $\max(0,g)$ to $g_+$. So for $g\sim\mathrm{N}_{0,1}$ half the time $g_+=0$.

Comment: You seem to have changed the order of operations: if you are computing the last formula in the question, then you need to compute the positive part of $g^2$, not the square of the positive part of $g$.

Comment: @whuber I was addressing the equation in the question title, which at the time I posted was equivalent to "Is $\mathbb{E}\big[(x^Tg)_+(g^Ty)_+\big] = (x^Ty)_+$ ?"